# Can't Mount SSHFS via FSTAB, but can mount via CLI. How do I get FSTAB to mount properly?

Tags: fstab, sshfs, fuse

I have setup password less SSH access and it works properly. I'm unable to automatically mount my SSHFS.

This works:

```
sshfs root@192.168.0.2:/vmfs/volumes/ESATA01/ ~/VPS
```

However, when inserted into my FSTAB, my logged in user get this

```
sshfs#root@192.168.0.2:/vmfs/volumes/ESATA01/   /home/amahi/VPS      fuse defaults,idmap=user 0 0
```

[image]

I definitely have a permissions issue as here related to where the mount point is. It seems that when I do the raw fuse mount from the CLI, I'm doing it as the non-sudo logged in user. If I mount from fstab, it's being done as sudo.

If I run nautilus as sudo, I'm able to get to the contents of the SSHFS.

Any input is appreciated.

Comment: Try the option `allow_other`, like: `defaults,idmap=user,allow_other`.

Comment: Thanks @EricCarvalho. That worked. I was banging my head against the wall for several hours...

Comment: Best not to use sshfs as root.

Comment: Please remember to use `allow_other` together with `default_permissions` or you will have a security problem. See comments to some similar questions here to know why.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps a more elegant way to do this would be to tell mount that:

- this mountpoint is a network device (so it can check it)
- this mountpoint shouldn't be automounted, but rather on-demand

Example:

```
me@svr:/movies  /MOUNTPOINT  fuse.sshfs noauto,x-systemd.automount,_netdev 0 0
```

From https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Sshfs

Comment: This solution is also great because you won't need another hacked "solution" for system-shutdown (for example you don't need to create a script that will unmount your sshfs when rebooting, etc)

Answer (score 1):

Per Eric's reply, I needed to add "allow_other" into my FSTAB entry. Once I did that, I was able to mount properly; however, It didn't work properly on reboot.

I discovered that because of the timing of the network coming up, I needed create a delay mechanism. I also needed to add the _netdev paramater to the end of my FSTAB entry.

I found the following [here](http://www.strato-faq.co.uk/artikel.html?articleid=1916)

```
If the automatic mounting procedure following a reboot is not successful, it may be because the drive is not yet ready when executing “fstab”.  To remedy this, please just enter the following lines in the file “/etc/rc.local” in front of the line “exit 0”:

sleep 20
mount -a

You can progressively reduce the value 20 until it is just sufficient to mount your Drive successfully after a reboot.
```