# Mounting (Bookmarking) remote directories over SSH via bash script?

Tags: 20.04, bash, mount, scripts, ssh

I'm pretty unfamiliar with Ubuntu and Linux in general, but we have a LAN in our office that all talk to a remote box for storage. On the client systems, I have to open up the file explorer and select "Other Locations" and then issue the following in the prompt:

```
ssh://<user>@<host>
```

Once logged in, I then navigate to a particular directory and drag it over to the sidebar and select "Add Bookmark".

For some reason this unmounts on occasion and I wanted to write a bash script that I can just double click or run via the terminal to do all this. The boxes are all running Ubuntu 20.04 and do not have internet access; some libraries have been downloaded and available via `sudo apt-install` but not many.

Not sure where to start in terms of Ubuntu or Linux commands, more of a Windows user, so I don't have any "what have you tried" worthy material (plus I cannot copy it over here anyhow).

Comment: Clicking on the bookmark should mount it again.

Comment: @user68186 Sometimes, but it would just be nice to run a script regardless, for setting up new boxes.

Comment: AFAIK there is no way to script that would make a bookmark for you in Nautilus (AKA Files), but I may be wrong. Instead of `ssh://<user>@<host>` you may want to try `sftp://<user>@<host>/full/path/to/your/folder`. ssh and sftp use the same protocol. If you are using password, you may want to try private-public key pair instead.

Comment: You may also want to take a look at [this question and its answers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/309347/cant-mount-sshfs-via-fstab-but-can-mount-via-cli-how-do-i-get-fstab-to-mount).

Answer (score 2):

You can mount the remote file system over ssh using `sshfs` command, then interact  with it as if it were a local system.

There is a man page here:
https://linux.die.net/man/1/sshfs
which gives the syntax for the command:

`sshfs [user@]host:[dir] mountpoint [options]`

Another tool in the wonderful ssh toolbox!